# Puppet - unable to execute ONLY ONCE ordered chain of Exec commands after notification

Tags: vagrant, manifest, puppet, redmine, puppet-enterprise

**TLDR:**

I can't configure ordered chain of Puppet "Exec" commands to run ONLY ONCE.

**Details:**

I want to use Vagrant and Puppet modules to setup VM with installed Redmine and some sample data loaded into it.
I'm using https://forge.puppetlabs.com/johanek/redmine and it works great - Redmine is installed and it works.

**My goal:**
Now I want to load sample data into Redmine using REST API:

1. Create 1 test project
2. Import 2 issues into this project

I want to run 2 simple "Exec", one after another and ONLY ONCE, but I can't achieve this, hence the question.

**My current effort:**
I've tried to subscribe to one of latest steps in redmine installation

> subscribe  => [Exec['rails_migrations']]

and then import data, but the first step "create-project1" *always* notifies second step "import-issues", so it creates duplicated data.
And if run vagrant provision few times, the "import-issues" creates duplicates of this issues.
Here is my code:

```
exec {'create-project1':
    subscribe => [Exec['rails_migrations']],
    path    => ['/usr/bin', '/usr/sbin', '/bin'],
    creates => "$redmine_install_dir/.data_loaded",
    command => "curl WHICH_CREATES_PROJECT && touch $redmine_install_dir/.data_loaded",
    notify  => [Exec['import-issues']],
} ->
exec {'import-issues':
    path    => ['/usr/bin', '/usr/sbin', '/bin'],
    command => "curl WHICH_IMPORTS_ISSUES",
    refreshonly => true,
}
```

**Question:**
How to configure those Exec commands to run in chain and ONLY ONCE?

Im also thinking about extending this chain to 5 commands in near future, so keep that in mind.

Answer (score 0):

you were almost there with 'ONLY ONCE' - Puppet has [onlyif](http://puppetcookbook.com/posts/exec-onlyif.html) properties that you can include in your exec block to test if a file already exists or not.

you could then do something like

```
exec {'create-project1':
    subscribe => [Exec['rails_migrations']],
    path    => ['/usr/bin', '/usr/sbin', '/bin'],
    onlyif  => "test ! -f $redmine_install_dir/.data_loaded"
    command => "curl WHICH_CREATES_PROJECT && touch $redmine_install_dir/.data_loaded",
    notify  => [Exec['import-issues']],
```

which test on the existence of the `$redmine_install_dir/.data_loaded`- you should be able to play a bit with that to achieve what you want

Comment: I've tested this solution - it prevent 'command' to execute, but the 'notify' still triggers refresh to next event. The real question is, can this 'notify' be stopped/unscheduled to notify next 'exec'? In future, when I would have e.g. 10 execs in chain, I probably would need to add 'onlyif' to all of them?